# Hotkey to get back to Object Mode from Weight Paint

Tags: shortcut, object-mode

Sometimes, when I think I'm in Edit Mode but I'm actually in Object Mode, I'll hit Ctrl-Tab, and I get switched into Weight Paint mode. Is there a hotkey that will reliably take me back to Object Mode? Hitting Ctrl-Tab again seems to work some of the time, but other times it does nothing, and I can't see any pattern to whether it'll work or not.

Comment: Actually this is not how it works for me.... I always get the pie menu where I can select which mode I want to change to.when I hit CTRL+TAB. But whatever mode I'm in, TAB enters Edit Mode and switches back to the previous mode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I caught the pattern.

**Ctrl + Tab** works if you was in **Object Mode** then you go to **Weight Paint Mode** and with doing nothing you're hitting **Ctrl + Tab** again.

But if after **Object Mode** you switched to **Weight Paint Mode** and then pressed **Tab** (in order to switch to  **Edit Mode**) then you can't switch to **Object Mode** using **Ctrl + Tab**

I solved this issue just adding a new keymap in settings, see screenshot. Hope it'll help you somehow.

[image]

Comment: That was just what I needed! It's a shame it took me so long to see it.
For anyone who sees this and is clueless about modifying key bindings, here's a step-by-step:

From the main menu, Edit > Preferences. In the preferences window that appears, select Keymap on the left, as shown. In the drill-down menu on the right, expand 3D View > Weight Paint, and there will be a button at the bottom of the list to add a new entry. Do that, and make it look like the picture, then you're done!